# NSwag-generated TypeScript uses camelCase while .net5 webapi configured to return PascalCase JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, nswag

I have a .net5 webapi controller, which returns JSON responses in PascalCase:

> [{"Email":"user@email.com","Id":16820,"Name":"User LastName","Phone":null}, ...

... achieved by either of the following configurations, the included System.Text.Json serializer:

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

or by referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` and configuring for NewtonSoftJSON.net:

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(c => c.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

We don't use `JsonProperty` or anything of that sort to decorate members of the DTOs

Using NSwagStudio [image: studio version]

or CLI [image: cli version],

the generated OpenApi spec is correctly generating the models in PascalCase, but the generated TypeScript interfaces and classes use camelCase, e.g.:

```
export interface IContact {
    email?: string | undefined;
    id: number;
    name?: string | undefined;
    phone?: string | undefined;
    ...
}
```

We need the generated interface and class members to be in PascalCase.

In addition to switching back to Newtonsoft, I also played with multiple inputs and settings in NSwagStudio to generate the above interface members in PascalCase to no avail. My understanding was that NSwag defers the serialization to the c# project settings so that generated code matches the .net core serializer output, but either that's not happening in my case or I am misinterpreting something.

Is it possible to configure nSwag to generate TypeScript (Angular template) classes and interfaces (incl. their members) in PascalCase?

Comment: In 2018, NSwag's owner [Rico Suter commented](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1258#issuecomment-378892015):
`The casing in the interfaces is exactly as the properties in the Swagger spec, because in an interface, we cannot rename them (they must exactly match the received JSON structure).`

Comment: To generate Pascal property names set "defaultPropertyNameHandling" to "PascalCase" in the nswag.json file. You can also setup auto code generation during compile time. See more here https://thecodeframework.com/how-to-auto-generate-net-6-web-api-client-code-in-typescript-during-build/